# How to make client wait for server to finish running a script?

Tags: javascript

I have a web client getting arguments from a user and submitting a form to server with a simple HTML submit form.

Server is running a script that sometimes may take several minutes to finish.

When the script is running more than a couple of minutes the client is re-submitting the form, instead of waiting for the first submit to finish.

How can I prevent that from happening?

**Example code:**

Submit form:

```
<form action="/testCall"> 
   <button type="submit" name="Button">Submit</button>        
</form>
```

Calling command on server:

```
app.get('/testCall', function(req,res){
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var cmd = "myCommand";
    exec(cmd, function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
        res.render('newPage.html', {data: stdout});
    });
});
```

In this case `myCommand` will run for a long time and the client will attempt to resubmit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the advice by RemcoGerlich was really good, my problem was that nodeJS blocked requests that ran for too long (more than two minutes)

To resolve that you have to disable response timeout in nodeJS backend code:

Something like this:

```
app.post('/testCall', function(req,res){

        var date = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
        res.setTimeout(0);
```

Took me a while to find that, hope it helps somebody out there!

Comment: Yes, this is one of the ways that you can get a timeout, you may also have a web server in front of Node, or caching, or internet provider proxies, or local browser settings... everything can decide two minutes is too much.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way it's usually done, a problem you don't mention is that some layer in between the user and your backend code may signal a Timeout at some point. Form submits really shouldn't take minutes.

It's more usual to start an *asynchronous task* on the server, using whatever technology you are using on the server side (apparently Node, but I don't know how it's done on Node), and then immediately return to the user to show him a page without the form, and instead some indication that the work is now under way.

Every now and then the page can then ask the server whether the task is already finished and then refresh itself with the result of the script, or perhaps the user can do that by hand.

Also, this script is started by a GET request. Please don't do that, GET requests aren't meant to change anything on the server. If you use a POST instead, then at least the browser will already show a warning when users mindlessly re-submit it with F5 (but users will also mindlessly ignored that warning).